# why does this cookie set in PHP keep returning null?

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set some cookie variables token variables received from twitter and am realizing that I keep getting a null variable for objects that are clearly not null...even for explicitly defined strings. Here is the specific code section I am working with though

```
var_dump($token->oauth_token);
    var_dump($token->oauth_token_secret); // these are not null

        // Attempt to save to cookies
    setcookie('oauth_token', $token->oauth_token);
    setcookie('oauth_token_secret', $token->oauth_token_secret);
    var_dump($_COOKIE['oauth_token']); //these cookie variables are null...holds true even for //simple strings...not just the complex twitter objects im working with...happens on chrome //and IE
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to reflash your page, and do you see the result? First time it will be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.php.net/setcookie (emphasis mine):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed **on the next page load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

Comment: And there should not be any output before the setcookie() call.

Comment: removed the var_dumps before cookie...added an expiration time...still null...is there a browser setting i can check?

Comment: +1!  setcookie() is an operation on the HTTP response.  $_COOKIE[] will give what was in the HTTP request, so setcookie() does not modify $_COOKIE (it has to go to the browser first, the browser may reject).  Set-Cookie is a response header, once your response body has been started (e.g. you've started sending some HTML) you can no longer set any response headers.

Comment: ok but i am not sending any html before setcookie anymore ....i have removed var_dump...are you saying $_COOKIE should stil be null  in that case?..if so what command sets $_COOKIE?...i want to set that so i cna access it on a different page..

Comment: Chrome will display cookies (CTRL+SHIFT+J -> Resources -> Cookies).  Firefox has a cookie inspector under Options -> Privacy -> remove individual cookies, although the LiveHTTPHeaders plugin is easier.  There's a HTTPHeaders for IE available from blunck.se, with the HTTP Headers plug ins, you can see the cookie's being set and the cookies being sent.

Comment: Cookies are restricted to the page you set them on unless you specify their scope with the path parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php, e.g. `setcookie('oauth_token', $token->oauth_token, $path='/');` (If I remember PHP syntax correctly)!   The path '/' means the cookie will be sent to every URL on your domain, if the 'www' in your domain is optional, then you might want to set the domain too for the cookie to apply to both those domains (with and without the 'www').